# Print information from database table in shopping site

Tags: php, database, for-loop, printing

I tried my best but I stuck on this problem. Sorry for my bad english.

So here is the situation:
I am trying to make a little shopping site. My database table looks like this:

```
id   pic        titel               desc                    price
1    gta5.png   Grand Theft Auto 5  A open world game...    49.99
2    cod.png    Call Of Duty: MW    A Ego-Shooter game...   59.99
3    play4.png  Playstation 4       Next-Gen Console...     249.99
4    contr.png  Ps4 Controller      Next-Gen Equipment...   69.99
```

On the Database Class file I have some function where I get the column information from the table:

```
public function getImg(){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($this->query)){
        return $row[1];
    }
}

public function getTitel(){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($this->query)){
        return $row[2];
    }
}

...
```

With getImg() I will get every information on the pic column like: gta5.png, cod.png etc.

My problem is starting here. I want to print out every column with a for loop on the index.php file. But I can't see any information. Here is the index.php file:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <?php 
                    for($i = 0; $i < $database->getTableLength(); $i++){
                ?>
                        <img src="image/<?php echo $database->getImg(); ?>"></img>
                        <h4><?php echo  $database->getTitel(); ?></h4>
                        <h5><?php echo  $database->getDesc(); ?></h5>
                        <h2><?php echo  $database->getPrice(); ?>€</h2>
                        <input type="button" name="submit" value="Buy">
                <?php 
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But as I said there is nothing. The getTableLength() function is the length of the table (In this case 4). I also tried to print it out one by one like this:

```
<ul>
        <li>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="content">
                    <?php 
                        for($i = 0; $i < $database->getTableLength(); $i++){
                            echo $database->getImg() . "<br>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

But again failed.. I can see even the br tag but not the information that I want to print out. When I put the echo line before the for loop, then I can see the first index of the column (gta5.png), but I want to have all columns.

Hope to see some solutions. Thanks for any kind of help!

**EDIT:** 
It is working when I write 5 instead of the length function:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
    echo $database->getImg();
}
```

But I still want to use that function. The getTableLength() function isn't working as I expected. There is nothing to see when I insert the function. The getTable function looks like this:

```
public function getTableLength(){
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM `$this->table`";
    $this->query = mysqli_query($this->connect, $sql);

    if($this->query){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($this->query);        
        return $row['num'];
    }
}
```

When I call it on the index.php file like:

```
$database->getTableLength();
```

I can see nothing and everything is gone. It's like buggy.

Comment: Add ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); to the top of your php code file and see if there are any erros.

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth Hey thank you for your response. I added those functions and there is no error..

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. It was to complicated. Think simple and do it better..

Here is the solution:

```
    <?php 

        $table = $database->getTableName();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `$table`";
        $connect = $database->getConn();
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){


    ?>
    <form method="post" action="index.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $row["id"] ?>">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="image/<?php echo $row["bild"]; ?>"></img>
                    <h4><?php echo $row["titel"]; ?></h4>
                    <h5><?php echo $row["beschreibung"]; ?></h5>
                    <h2><?php echo $row["preis"]; ?>€</h2>
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row["titel"]; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $row["preis"]; ?>">
                    <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" value="Kaufen">
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <?php
```